# Post fix file name with SML on windows using command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, rename, batch-rename

I have GUID based Image files such as

- ff568205-e82c-4be8-aca8-18f40ec64e5a.PNG
- 1f91e4e9-c163-4f28-acbc-dbb7693ef2e5.JPG

I have thousands of images folder and i need to rename all these file and add SML at the end of each image so that all my image will be renames to

- ff568205-e82c-4be8-aca8-18f40ec64e5aSML.PNG
- 1f91e4e9-c163-4f28-acbc-dbb7693ef2e5SML.JPG

I tried using few commands but got them all wrong one such command is

`*.* *SML.*` this renames the files but adds SML to the file extension

I am looking for resource which can help me do it using cmd prompt on windows.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be seperate from questions. You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: @DavidPostill, I kept it there think other may post answer in a better or more optimized way. anyways i have now posted it as an answer since no one replied

Answer (score 0):

I used following command

`ren *.* ?????????????????????????????????????"SML.*`